# How do I pass in an explicit parameter to a Range object?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the cell of the first row of where the Range object is set. Also avoiding using `Activate`, `Select` as well. The range is dynamic (being updated to a new row in a loop) so using `Offset` won't work.

Here's what I have:

```
Set curr_ws = Worksheets("Data")
Dim data_curr_rng As Range
tool_sel = curr_ws.Range(data_curr_rng.Address(0, 0)).Offset(-4).Value
'Regardless of the column number of `data_curr_rng`, I need the cell in that column's Row 1
```

I've been playing around with the variable data_curr_rng but can't seem to figure out the right functions/properties to use.

Comment: `curr_ws.Cells(1,ActiveCell.column)`

Comment: Does that require using `Activate` and `Select` beforehand? I'm not using those methods in my script

Comment: You referred to "where a cursor is located".

Comment: Ah you're right. I should've instead said "where the Range is set". Updated the OP

Comment: If your reference range is `data_curr_rng` just use that in place of `activecell`.

Comment: Any reason why the VBA Editor doesn't have the hint list appear after I type in `Cells(row, col).`? I can do `Cells(row, col).Value` but an intellisense-like list doesn't appear

Comment: @simplycoding I *guess* this is because `Cells()` is a function here, only the *returned* object has the `.Value` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Cells()` function of the `Worksheet`

```vb
my_row = 1
my_column = 5
Set my_range = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(my_row, my_column)
```

If you need to select a range of more than one cell you can wrap it in the `Range` like this

```vb
start_row = 1
start_column = 5
end_row = 10
end_column = 5
Set start_cell = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(start_row, start_column)
Set end_cell = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(end_row, end_column)
Set my_range = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(start_cell, end_cell)
```

Comment: The `Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).` can be substituted by `ActiveSheet.`, but it has proven useful to me to specify this for ranges since it is then easy to modify it for use with more worksheets(`Sheets(1)`) or workbook (`ThisWorkbook`) or Excel instances (`Application`).

Comment: I think @SJR has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972725/how-do-i-pass-in-an-explicit-parameter-to-a-range-object#comment98596194_55972725) the question already... I'm not sure your answer is relevant. OP isn't questioning the use of `Cells` or `Range`.

Comment: @BigBen I was answering the title of the question. I'm showing how to *pass an explicit parameter to a Range object*. I'm sorry if my answer bothered you, it was not the intention.

Comment: No bother at all, I see what you're getting at. I guess I'm just pointing out that OP isn't looking for a hard-coded column number. The title isn't the best.

Comment: Also `ActiveCell` `ActiveSheet` etc is not the best way to do everything. With my code you can work with more sheets/workbooks at the same time without being worried that you're gonna mess something up by randomly clicking one of the open excel windows. I still believe my answer can be helpful to people looking for "How to pass an explicit parameter to a Range object."

Comment: Thanks @reportgunner, this was in fact what I was initially aiming for, but instead of using variables like `my_row` and `my_column`, using some VBA object

Comment: I completely agree with avoiding `ActiveCell` and `ActiveSheet`. There was some confusion about whether we were considering the cursor position / `ActiveCell` when the comment was posted.

Comment: @simplycoding aha *now* I get it !

Comment: The unqualified `Range` call on the last line, is implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet`. This means error 1004 if `Sheets(1)` (the parent sheet of `start_cell` and `end_cell`) isn't active. You want to declare a `Worksheet` variable, and use it to qualify all ranges that are read from that sheet.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon have you tested it ? Since the child `Cells` object have a worksheet, the `Range` knows which worksheet it belongs to.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon try adding `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate` before the unqualified range call and `my_range.Interior.ColorIndex = 4` after the range call. Why is range in the **first** worksheet colored ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem you are describing happens if it's vice versa - unqualified `Cells` calls and qualified `Range` call. Why would I declare 50 worksheet variables when I can simply loop for each `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` ?

Comment: No, I didn't test it. If it reads wrong, it's wrong. Unqualified `Range` works differently depending on whether you're in a standard module (`[_Global].Range`) or in some worksheet's code-behind (`Me.Range`), and yes, in **this specific case** it's off whatever sheet these `Cells` are from - which is an even better reason to avoid unqualified `Range` calls. My opinion is that code written a certain way should do the same thing and work identically regardless of where it's written. "Hey look it works!" is good until someone copies the code and uses it in another context and it blows up.

Comment: Put that exact same code in the code-behind of `Sheet2`, and there you have it.

Comment: You're just moving the goalposts now.

Comment: No, I'm just saying `Range` needs to be qualified - no ifs, no buts.

Comment: I said you are moving the goalposts, because if I move the qualified `Range` call to a `Sheet2` then I get the same 1004 error.

Answer (score 0):

The Cursor is located have an code for this , ActiveCell , 
you can use ActiveCell combined with Row and .End()

The code below returns the first cell UP (Ctrl+UpArrow)

```
   ActiveCell.End(xlUp)
```

The code below

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is:

> ```
> Set curr_ws = Worksheets("Data")
> Dim data_curr_rng As Range
> tool_sel = curr_ws.Range(data_curr_rng.Address(0, 0)).Offset(-4).Value
> 'Regardless of the column number of `data_curr_rng`, I need the cell in that column's Row 1
> ```

What you are asking is to take the selected range, identified the full column, and then took the first cell (which will be Row 1).

```
Set curr_ws = Worksheets("Data")
Dim data_curr_rng As Range
Set data_curr_rng = [Something] ` your example does not note how you set this.
' *** The solution to your question is below
Dim firstCellInColumn as Range ` could be cell etc. - using this to illustrate the concept
Set firstCellInColumn = data_curr_rang.EntireColumn.Cells(1,1)
' *** The back to your code
tool_sel = firstCellInColumn.Value
```

The `EntireColumn` method returns a range, and then in my example above, I just took the first cell in that range.